# ImageView in Dialogue Box -Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am trying to save an image into my firebase database. I save my data using dialog box. What i want to now is that, i want to add images by clicking a button, then select the pic from my gallery. Now the i would want the the path of the photo to show on the dialogue and not the image itself. Save the path to firebase and retrieve the image itself into an imageview in another activity.

Is there any sample code to this please?

Comment: there are some samples how to get an image from the gallery where you get the path and show an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want to add images by clicking a button, then select the pic from my gallery.

Use Chooser to select an image from the gallery:

```
private void BtnClick_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.SetType("image/*");
    intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
    StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 0);
}
```

> the i would want the the path of the photo to show on the dialogue and not the image itself. Save the path to firebase and retrieve the image itself into an imageview in another activity.

By using chooser, you can retrieve the content Url from `OnActivityResult`:

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
     Android.Net.Uri uri = data.Data;
     string realFilePath=GetRealFilePath(uri);
     //post the realFilePath to Firebase here

     //store realFilePath locally to pass it to other activity
}
```

To store the path of the image in Firebase, you need to convert the content url to real path of the file by using following codes:

```
public string GetRealFilePath(Uri uri)
{
    var isDocumentUri = DocumentsContract.IsDocumentUri(this, uri);
    if (isDocumentUri)
    {
        string id = DocumentsContract.GetDocumentId(uri);
        string[] split = id.Split(':');
        string type = split[0];
        if (IsMediaDocument(uri))
        {
            Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".Equals(type))
            {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri;
                string selection = "_id=?";
                string[] selectionArgs = new string[] { split[1] };
                string filePath = GetDataColumn(this, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
                return filePath;
            }
        }
    }else
    {
      //when select the file directly from gallery, `isDocumentUri` will be false.
      var contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri;
      var selection = "_id=?";
      string[] selectionArgs = new string[] { uri.LastPathSegment };
      string filePath = GetDataColumn(this, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
      return filePath;
    }
    return null;
}

public  string GetDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, string selection,string[] selectionArgs)
{

    ICursor cursor = null;
    string column = "_data";
    string[] projection = {
        column
    };

    try
    {
        cursor = ContentResolver.Query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.MoveToFirst())
        {
            int column_index = cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.GetString(column_index);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.Close();
    }
    return null;
}

public static bool IsMediaDocument(Uri uri)
{
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".Equals(uri.Authority);
}
```